# Shape of curve with constant geometric parameter ratio

Tags: geometry

What shapes (apart from a semi-circle) should curves of length L have when keeping their ends on X-axis, enclose an area A between it and X-axis and have a constant ratio $L^2/ A = 2 \pi?$

Comment: just thinking aloud: have you considered reflection across the x-axis? You are aware of the isoperimetric inequality and the fact that the circle is the only curve for which equality is attained (I take you do not consider the x-axis as part of the curve).

Comment: I have not considered any curve cutting x-axis, but I know about the isoperimetric problem of Dido. My question is, when extremality is not mentioned explicitly , constancy and extremality are implied as one and the same concept in the language of calculus of variations? I avoided this tag. Is the semi-circle the  only solution? Also I did not specify as the object function Area/Length.(X axis is not part of considered curve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments, you should reflect in the x-axis. Then you will obtain a closed loop whose length is $\tilde{L}=2L$ and enclosed area is $\tilde{A}=2A$. Now apply the equality case of the isoperimetric theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoperimetric_inequality) which states that
$$ \tilde{L}^2/\tilde{A} = 4 \pi $$
if and only if the curve is a circle. Plugging in $L$ and $A$, you do get equality (by your hypothesis). Therefore you have a circle and the curve you start with is a semi-circle.